# Find Pi using integral

Tags: integration, pi

I am just started learning calculus and wonder why:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{4}{1+x^2}$$
Allows to find $\pi$?

It would be great if someone could provide very detailed explanation.

Comment: Do you know de derivative of $\arctan$?

Comment: No, i do not know what is a derivative of arctan.

Comment: Here you can find a good proof of that. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Arctangent_Function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x^2+1}dx=[\text{arctan}(x)]^1_{0}$$

Comment: Yes, I know that. But what to do next?

Comment: @Bob the result is equal to $\arctan(1)-\arctan(0)$. For which angles $\tan(x)=0$ and $\tan(x)=1$?

Comment: @rlartiga arctan(1) = 45 degrees and 45 * 4 = 180, which equals to Pi. Am I right?

Comment: @Bob yes $180$ degrees is $\pi$ in radians

Comment: @rlartiga Thanks for explaining - and Bob I can see you learned something, well done!

Answer (score 1):

As Nicky Hekster shows, we have

$$\int_0^1\frac1{1+x^2}\ dx=4\arctan(x)\bigg]_0^1=\pi$$

Then, as you may recall, we have the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series):

$$\frac1{1-r}=1+r+r^2+r^3+\dots$$

By setting $r=-x^2$, we get

$$\frac1{1+x^2}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\dots$$

Integrating and you'll get

$$\int_0^1\frac1{1+x^2}\ dx=\int_0^11-x^2+x^4-x^6+\dots\ dx=x-\frac13x^3+\frac15x^5-\frac17x^7+\dots\bigg]_0^1$$

That is, we end up with the [famous Leibniz formula for $\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80):

$$\frac\pi4=1-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\dots$$

Which is just too beautiful!  Is it not?  From here, using different special angles, we can arrive at various different formulas for $\pi$ that converge much faster than the one above.  Alternatively, you could also apply an Euler sum to the above series expansion as I have described in this answer:

[How to prove this $\pi$ formula?](http://How%20to%20prove%20this%20%CF%80%20formula?)